# How to get python to generate the tweedie deviance for xgboost?

Tags: xgboost

Using statsmodel's GLM, the tweedie deviance is included in the summary function, but I don't know how to do this for xgboost. Reading the API didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python this is how you do it. Suppose `predictions` is the result of your gradient boosted tree and `real` are the actual numbers. Then using `statsmodels` you would run this:

```
import statsmodels as sm

dev = sm.families.Tweedie(pow_var=1.5).deviance(predictions, real)
```